# Python Game of inbetween - can't get if-elif to work

Tags: python, if-statement

trying to make a game in Python.. although I can't seem to get a certain bit of code working?! It's driving me nuts!

Any help is greatly appreciated!

```
import random

die1 = random.randint(1,10)
die2 = random.randint(1,10)
die3 = random.randint(1,10)


if die1 > die2:
    print ('Die 1:', die2,'  Die 2:', die1,)
else:
    print ('Die 1:', die1,'  Die 2:', die2,)

    if die1 == die2 or die2 == die1:
        print('\nEven-steven!')
    else:
        print('\nNot the same, let\'s play!')

print ('\nDie 3:', die3,)



if die3 > die1 and die3 < die2 or die3 < die1 and die3 > die2: 
    print ('\n*** You win! ***')
elif die1 > die2:
    if die3 < die2 or die3 > die1:
        print('\n*** Sorry - You lose! ***')
elif die2 > die1:
    if die3 < die1 or die3 > die2:
        print('\n*** Sorry - You lose! ***')
**elif die3 == die1 or die3 == die2:
    print ('\n*** You hit the post - You lose double your bet! ***')**


print ('\nThanks for playing!')
```

It's in the second if statement structure, and for whatever reason if die1 or die2 are the same as die3, it just won't print 'You hit the post...' it just ends!

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By simplifying your code it will be much easier to debug. There are only 3 conditions  `win`,`lose` or `lose (double)` so there doesn't need to be 6 *(nested)* conditionals. Also by switching `die1` and `die2` if `die1 > die2` your program output and variables stay meaningful. This is saner:

```
import random

die1 = random.randint(1,10)
die2 = random.randint(1,10)

if die1 > die2:
    die1, die2 = die2, die1

print('Die 1:',die1,'Die 2:',die2)

if die1 == die2:
    print('Even-steven!')
else:
    print("Not the same, let's play!")  

    die3 = random.randint(1,10) 
    print('Die 3:',die3)

    if die3 > die1 and die3 < die2 or die3 < die1 and die3 > die2: 
        print ('You win!')
    elif die3 == die1 or die3 == die2:
        print ('You hit the post - You lose double your bet!')
    else:
        print('Sorry - You lose!')

print('Thanks for playing!')
```

Answer (score 1):

Your diagnosis is incorrect. The last statement *will* match if `die3` is equal to either `die1` or `die2`:

```
>>> die1, die2 = 1, 2
>>> die3 = die1
>>> die3 == die1 or die3 == die2
True
>>> die3 = die2
>>> die3 == die1 or die3 == die2
True
```

However, if `die1` is greater than `die2` your *first* `elif` matches, but your comparison to `die3` is flawed:

```
>>> die1, die2 = 2, 1
>>> die3 = die1
>>> die3 < die2 or die3 > die1
False
```

and *nothing* is ever printed. You need to clean up the logic for that case.

Since you only have 3 different outcomes; winning, losing and hitting the post, you can really simplify the whole thing down to:

```
if die1 < die3 < die2:
    print('\n*** You win! ***')
elif die3 == die1 or die3 == die2:
    print('\n*** You hit the post - You lose double your bet! ***')
else:
    print('\n*** Sorry - You lose! ***')
```

Note that I used [chained comparisons](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/expressions.html#not-in) to simplify the first `if` expression some more. You also made sure that `die1` is lower than `die2`, so testing for `die2 < die3 < die1` is *always* going to be `False`.

Another note: `==` should be transitive, so `die1 == die2 or die2 == die1` is redundant. You can simplify that to just `die1 == die2`.

Simplifying your whole program:

```
import random

die1 = random.randint(1,10)
die2 = random.randint(1,10)

if die1 > die2:
    die1, die2 = die2, die1

print ('Die 1:', die1,'  Die 2:', die2,)

if die1 == die2:
    print('Even-steven!')
else:
    print("Not the same, let's play!")
    die3 = random.randint(1,10)

    print ('Die 3:', die3)

    if die1 < die3 < die2:
        print('\n*** You win! ***')
    elif die3 == die1 or die3 == die2:
        print('\n*** You hit the post - You lose double your bet! ***')
    else:
        print('\n*** Sorry - You lose! ***')

print ('Thanks for playing!')
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of letting it drive you nuts, stay calm, and use [`pdb`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/pdb.html#debugger-commands).

```
if die3 in (die1, die2):
    import pdb; pdb.set_trace()

if die3 > die1 and die3 < die2 or die3 < die1 and die3 > die2: 
    print ('\n*** You win! ***')
elif die1 > die2:
    if die3 < die2 or die3 > die1:
        print('\n*** Sorry - You lose! ***')
elif die2 > die1:
    if die3 < die1 or die3 > die2:
        print('\n*** Sorry - You lose! ***')
**elif die3 == die1 or die3 == die2:
    print ('\n*** You hit the post - You lose double your bet! ***')**


print ('\nThanks for playing!')
```

Now run it, and when it breaks, start debugging (using `n` for next, check value of each condition, etc.).

Answer (score 0):

The `elif` for the final if statement only gets processed together as part of the alternative solution for the 3rd condition's inner `if` statement.

The following should fix your problem.  Note the changes

```
if die3 > die1 and die3 < die2 or die3 < die1 and die3 > die2: 
    print ('\n*** You win! ***')
elif die1 > die2 and (die3 < die2 or die3 > die1):
    print('\n*** Sorry - You lose! ***')
elif die2 > die1 and (die3 < die1 or die3 > die2):
    print('\n*** Sorry - You lose! ***')
elif (die3 == die1) or (die3 == die2):
    print ('\n*** You hit the post - You lose double your bet! ***')
```

Enjoy. :)

Answer (score 0):

How about this?

```
if die3 == die1 or die3 == die2:
    print ('\n*** You hit the post - You lose double your bet! ***')
else:
    if die3 > die1 and die3 < die2 or die3 < die1 and die3 > die2: 
        print ('\n*** You win! ***')
    elif die1 > die2:
        if die3 < die2 or die3 > die1:
            print('\n*** Sorry - You lose! ***')
    elif die2 > die1:
        if die3 < die1 or die3 > die2:
            print('\n*** Sorry - You lose! ***')
```